# SQL Troubleshooting in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, inventory-management

Alright, here is my issue.

Working on a Inventory Control program, and got it mostly done, when a wild bug appears.
The system will check out a item, but will not check it back in, even though it throws all the proper messages that it does check the item in.

What's worse, is that the SQL statement is encapsulated in a try-catch class and acts as if nothing is wrong, and does not throw an exception.

And this is just a functional build, not a streamlined one, so it looks a little rough.

The statement in question is:

`Dim OleCheckIn As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Assets SET [Checked Out]='Checked In' WHERE [ID Number]=" + sBarcode + "", OleDbConn)`

I am sure it is something very very obvious, but I have been rebuilding and staring at it for so long, I am likely glossing over a glaring hole in it.

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Public EmpIDFlag As Boolean
Public ItemBCode As Boolean
Public CheckFlag As Boolean
Public dEmpID As Double
Public sEmpID As String
Public dbEmpID As Double
Public dBarcode As Double
Public sBarcode As String
Public sFirstName As String
Public sLastName As String
Public sFullName As String
Public sItem As String
Public sCheckedOut As String
Public sCheckedOutBy As String
Public OleDbConn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\rcassel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Inventory Control\Inventory Control\Inventory Control2.accdb;")


Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
    dEmpID = (Val(TextBox1.Text))

    'Checks to see if someone entered a Badge
    If dEmpID = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("You must scan your Badge!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox1.Focus()
    Else
        sEmpID = dEmpID.ToString
        'Fire Query into Database
        Try
            OleDbConn.Open()
            Dim OleEmp As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [First Name],[Last Name],[Employee ID] FROM Contacts WHERE [Employee ID]=" + sEmpID + "", OleDbConn)

            Dim r1 As OleDbDataReader = OleEmp.ExecuteReader()

            While r1.Read()
                sFirstName = CStr(r1("First Name"))
                sLastName = CStr(r1("Last Name"))
                dbEmpID = CInt(r1("Employee ID"))
            End While

            r1.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox("Cannot Pull Data." & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try

        If dbEmpID = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("You are not Authorised to use this device. This activity has been logged.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

        Else
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(sFirstName)
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(sLastName)
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(sEmpID)
            TextBox2.Focus()
        End If

        OleDbConn.Close()
    End If

End Sub

'Item Barcode
'Private Sub TextBox2_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.LostFocus
Private Sub Textbox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    dBarcode = (Val(TextBox2.Text))
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then

        sBarcode = dBarcode.ToString()
        OleDbConn.Open()
        Try
            Dim OleItem As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Item],[Checked Out],[Checked out Last by] FROM Assets WHERE [ID Number]=" + sBarcode + "", OleDbConn)
            Dim r2 As OleDbDataReader = OleItem.ExecuteReader()

            While r2.Read()
                sItem = CStr(r2("Item"))
                sCheckedOut = CStr(r2("Checked Out"))
                sCheckedOutBy = CStr(r2("Checked out Last by"))

            End While
            ItemBCode = True

            'Set Checkout Flag, this will be called later by the Check In/Check Out button
            If sCheckedOut = "Checked Out" Then
                CheckFlag = True
            End If

                r2.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Barcode Invalid." & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            ItemBCode = False
        End Try
        If ItemBCode = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.Items.Add(sItem)
            Me.ListBox2.Items.Add(sCheckedOut)
            Me.ListBox2.Items.Add(sCheckedOutBy)
        End If
        OleDbConn.Close()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

'This is the "Check In" button
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ItemBCode = False Then
        MsgBox("You must have a Valid Item Barcode!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox2.Focus()
    Else
        If CheckFlag Then
            Try
                OleDbConn.Open()
                    Dim OleCheckIn As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Assets SET [Checked Out]='Checked In' WHERE [ID Number]=" + sBarcode + "", OleDbConn)

                    MsgBox("This Item has been Checked in!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Barcode Invalid." & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
                    ItemBCode = False
                End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("This Item is already Checked in!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            TextBox2.Focus()
        End If
    End If
    OleDbConn.Close()
End Sub

'This is the "Check Out" button
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If ItemBCode = False Then
        MsgBox("You must have a Valid Item Barcode!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox2.Focus()
    Else
        If CheckFlag = False Then
            Try
                sFullName = String.Format("{0} {1}", sFirstName, sLastName)
                OleDbConn.Open()
                Dim OleCheckOut As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Assets SET [Checked Out]='Checked Out',[Checked out Last by] ='" + sFullName + "' WHERE [ID Number]=" + sBarcode + "", OleDbConn)

                MsgBox("This Item has been Checked Out!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Barcode Invalid." & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
                ItemBCode = False
            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("This Item is already Checked Out!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            TextBox2.Focus()
        End If
    End If
    OleDbConn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use ampersand & instead of + when working with strings, + is meant for arithmetic. `...[Employee ID]=" + sEmpID + "", O...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never execute your update commands:

```
OleCheckIn.ExecuteNonQuery()

OleCheckOut.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Also, use parameters.  You are exposing your system to SQL injection.